# How do you retrieve the commit message and file list for a particular revision?

Tags: svn, version-control

I need to deploy a few files that were checked in sometime ago (can't remember the exact ones), so I'm looking to get a list so I can deploy just those files. What is the svn command to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`svn log` has a `--verbose` parameter. I don't have a repository here to test with, but does that return a list of modified files?

You can also use `svn diff -r <revision>` to retrieve the full change details, which you can parse or read manually to find out which files were changed.

Comment: Yes, svn log -v -r <#> does work, however I discovered that the message won't be displayed (or will be incomplete) if you aren't above the committed files in the directory tree.

Answer (score 9):

@Dana & @John

Actually, `svn log -v -r <#> http://my.svn.server/repository-root` will work and show you all modified files within this repository.  Or if you wanted this to work from within a working copy, you could use the output of `svn info | grep Repository Root` or something to find the actual repository root.

`--verbose` is the same as `-v`, and those options simply list all of the affected files.